# Pandas - Use values from rows with equal values in iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

In case this has been answered in the past I want to apologize, I was not sure how to phrase the question.
I have a dataframe with 3d coordinates and rows with a scalar value (magnetic field in this case) for each point in space. I calculated the radius as the distance from the line at (x,y)=(0,0) for each point. The unique radius and z values are transferred into a new dataframe. Now I want to calculate the scalar values for every point (Z,R) in the volume by averaging over all points in the 3d system with equal radius.

Currently I am iterating over all unique Z and R values. It works but is awfully slow.

df is the original dataframe, dfn is the new one which - in the beginning - only contains the unique combinations of R and Z values.

```py
for r in dfn.R.unique():
    for z in df.Z.unique():
        dfn.loc[(df["R"]==r)&(df["Z"]==z), "B"] = df["B"][(df["R"]==r)&(df["Z"]==z)].mean()
```

Is there any way to speed this up by writing a single line of code, in which pandas is given the command to grab all rows from the original dataframe, where Z and R have the values according to each row in the new dataframe?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html)!!!

It looks like you can achieve with something like:
`df[['R', 'Z', 'B']].groupby(['R', 'Z']).mean()`